# JavaScript: Not calling javascript function from the code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have made one .aspx page to upload the image file.

Page 1 - from there I am opening Page2.aspx using window.open(small size like dialogbox) in js.

Then in Page 2 Javascript I have below WindowRefresh() function to refresh Page 1 and close Page 2(once file upload completes).

That is the reason I have used 'window.opener.location.href' to refer Parent Page(Page 1).

In Page 2 I have below Windowrefresh() function to refresh the parent window and it will close the Upload dialog window.

```
 function Windowrefresh() {
        if (window.navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
            window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            self.close();
        }
        else if (window.navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            window.close();
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to call this function from the code behind of Page 2 when one session variable has some value.

I tried below things.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "Windowrefresh();", true);
```

And,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "Windowrefresh()", true);
```

But it is neither refreshing Page 1 nor Closing Page 2.

I am not sure what is wrong in this.

Comment: check console for any errors.

Comment: How often does this block get hit? `window.navigator.appName == "Netscape"`. Loads i'd bet.

Comment: `window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;`??

Comment: You're calling code to refresh the page ... when the page has just been refreshed by a PostBack? Why are you doing that?

Comment: It is not getting refreshed by postback. It just stays on that upload file dialog page.

Comment: @user1671639 - Yes..I checked the errors and it shows me - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier .. I am not sure why it is.

Comment: @MittalPatel Check the line number, where the error occurred.

Comment: Please check my question again - I have updated it with more detail. Thank you,

Comment: @user1671639 - It shows below error message - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier /CompanyLogoUpload.aspx?UserType=e&AsyncFileUploadID=AsyncFileUpload1&rnd=0617503494489938:185    *********************  but there is not 185 line in my aspx page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this.. I have not tested the code...... In the child window

`<body onunload="refreshParent();">`

```
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

 {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
```

close the child window when you have the session variable...(i dont know asp so cant help you with that syntax)

Comment: Srikanth - Thanks for your reply. I am trying your code now. But, I will not be able to access Session variable here in the body tag to check whether I have to refresh parent this time or not. That is the reason I want to call this function from code behind, where I have session variable to control this refresh. - Thanks

Comment: where is the session variable? parent or pop up window?

Comment: Srikanth - I can access Session variable in pop up window .cs file. And there I want to call this function to refresh the parent and close the popup. Thanks